# blazor webassembly windows authentication

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

So, these two are two are years old. I saw some changes in libraries from .Net 6 to .Net 7

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66009663/blazor-webassembly-windows-authentication-netcore-hosted)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62879686/blazor-webassembly-authentication)

I want to know if there is anything changed.
Can we implement windows authentication in Blazor Webassembly.
Can we get Environment.UserName is webassembly?
Can we get all Cliams in webassembly?